# Why can 'Others' read settings.php by default?

Tags: configuration

By default, `settings.php` has its permissions set to 404, which means 'Others' can read the file. Why not set it to 400, so that only the user can read the file? Thanks.

Comment: As noted in the answers, the reason for making the file readable from users that are not the owner and are not in the same group as the owner doesn't depend from Drupal, but from the server. This question is not Drupal-specific.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this default, I believe, is because on some hos plans (e.g. bargain basement shared hosting), the web server user is *not* by default the owner of the file.  On some hosting plans, it may not even be an option to use commands such as `chown` and `chmod` to set up things exactly the way you want.

The web server user *must* be able to read this file to get access to DB credentials, and on such hosting plans, allowing "Other" to read is the only way to achieve that.  (Having `400` as the default would most certainly create a deluge of support requests from people unable to figure out why Drupal can't access their database.)

If you know what you're doing, it is OK to 1) make sure the file is owned by the web server user, and 2) set permissions to `400`.

Answer (score 1):

settings.php should be chmod 644 according too https://drupal.org/documentation/install/settings-file

It's more of a general rule then a requirement. Really it depends how apache runs itself (ie. what user they run as). What ever user they run as needs to have read permissions to that file.